# SQL Group by Count and Date

Tags: sql

I have two tables

Table 1:

```
'table1Id' int,
'date' date
```

Table 2:

```
'table2Id' int,
'table1Id' int,
'switchVal' int DEFAULT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY 'table1Id' REFERENCES table1('table1Id')
```

How do I go about displaying the count table1Id grouped by date assuming that `switchVal` is `not null`?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Those single quotes are confusing me.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT        SUM(dbo.Table_1.table1Id) AS Expr1, dbo.Table_2.switch1val, dbo.Table_1.date
FROM            dbo.Table_1 INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Table_2 ON dbo.Table_1.table1Id = dbo.Table_2.table1id
GROUP BY dbo.Table_2.switch1val, dbo.Table_1.date
HAVING        (dbo.Table_2.switch1val IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Had to make a couple small changes to this, but this helped immensely. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, give is an upvote if that worked for you.

Comment: Why did you put switch1val IS NOT NULL in the HAVING clause instead of in WHERE?

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the tables and group by based on the column table1Id.

```
Select t1.date, count(t1.table1Id) as 'Count' from Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2 on t1.table1Id = t2.table1Id
where t2.[switchVal] is not null
group by t1.date
```